# how to add values in a character list and stop adding if the next values is null in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have a 2D array . Below is my input

APPLE.CHIK

P.B.

ESCAPE.OTHER

Each of the above input represents a CHARACTER and '.' represents NULL character. The values are in 2D array . I want to add the values to a list, continue adding and stop if the next value is '.' .

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :**

APPLE CHIK ESCAPE OTHER

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**

APPLCHIESCAPOTHE

As you can see, the letter 'E' from the "APPLE" , 'K' from "CHIK" , 'E' from "ESCAPE" and 'R' from "OTHER" is not added to the list as it fails the condition

I have tried the following code,

```
            if (((j + 1) < box[i].length ) && (box[i][j+1]!= null))
            {

                ans.add(box[i][j].getSolution());

            }
```

I even tried the below code,

```
        if (((j + 1) < box[i].length ) && (box[i][j]!= null))
            {

                ans.add(box[i][j].getSolution());

            }
```

When I tried this, **output** was,

APPLECHIC**PB**ESCAPEOTHER

But I don't want the characters 'P' and 'B' to get added as it doesn't have any characters coming behind.

In code, 'ans' is a character list. I am checking if the next box is not null then, add the values to character list. But since 'APPLE' has next character as null value, when it reaches the character 'E' in a loop, the condition fails and the character 'E' is not added in a list. But I mustn't miss "IF NEXT VALUE IS NULL" condition as it will affect my game logic.

so, I need the following to be achieved,

Iterate the 2D array add the values to the character list and stop if the next value is null

Since the values are added to character list, I don't know how to group the chararactes again to show it as a meaningful word.So, Is it possible to add the filtered values to string array ?

NOTE: Its a puzzle game and the inputs here are the "ACROSS CLUES" in a grid

Comment: What is the logic behind converting `"CHIK"` to `"CHIC"` and removal of `'P', null, 'B'` and convert `null` to 'Space'?

Comment: Its typo . Its a cross word and null represents black boxes in the grid. @Blip

Comment: What do you mean by `'.' represents NULL character`? The character represented by `\u0000` or a `null` reference? What type is `box[][]`?

Comment: Consider '.' represents a black box in a cross word . Its used to show that it has nothing  and box[i][j] is array of objects of type Box class. Don't consider that now @SubOptimal

Answer (score 0):

The problem (in your first approach) is that you add only characters which are not followed by `null`. Means each last character (e.g. APPL**E**) will not be added.

If you don't want to add single characters (e.g. `P.`) maybe you should check first if the number of charcaters before the `null` is bigger then one.

Then loop over all characters and add them to `ans` till you find the `null`.